# Making a private post visitable by link?

Tags: posts, private

I would like to know if it is possible to have a private post that can be visited by link. From what I understand, private posts can be only viewed by registered users, not guests. But I would like to make my private posts visitable by guests that have the link to the post.

Comment: I've removed the request for a plugin as it would have meant closing your question as offtopic. If you want recommendations you should ask this on the software recommendations stack instead, this stack is a programmers stack. Also, it sounds like you don't want private posts this is just a solution you've devised. What you're actually interested in is "unlisted posts", that are public but don't appear in feeds or listed in archives/widgets/etc. That would be much easier to implement than messing around with the private status, even though the result is the same

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm open to custom code solutions as well. Could you tell me how I could implement these "unlisted posts"?